# Power point spell checker flags every i letter inside words. How to fix this?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, spell-check

This is a weird one, but I am writing some notes for a slide and there's some weird spell checking flagging. The most obvious one is flagging every i in every word. For example:

meet**i**ng d**i**scussed flex**i**b**i**l**i**ty

If I right click just before I, it suggest that maybe I meant **I** or a/if/in/is. If I click on I, it modifies meeting to meetIng. Somehow it thinks every new character is it's own word, although there are also some other odd suggestions like:

a**nd** where only **nd** is underlined with the squiggly line, the suggestion is **and**. If I click on it, I end up with *aand*

My selected language is English (Europe), but for some odd reason some words are considered to be English (United Kingdom) and some other words are considered to be English (United States). Again for some odd reason, only words that are not English (Europe) are wrongly flagged. Although not all non-Europe are flagged.

Things I've tried: Deleting the entire text and rewriting it. Didn't work, somehow Power Point decides that *sent* is an English (Europe) word, while **a** *nd* is **US** and *UK*

Did this ever happen to anyone? Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: It can be interesting and fun to figure out the "why" of these odd behaviors, but sometimes it's best to hit it with the biggest FIX IT hammer you can find and move one. Try Control Panel, Programs & Features, find Office and do a repair to see if that helps. For O365, try the quick repair first; if you go for the major one, you may be looking at a reinstall, so you may need your install credentials.

Answer (score 2):

we had the same issue. When writing the word "ceiling", both "i" were underlined by the spellchecker.  The user had multiple languages installed, 3 versions of English (UK, US, and German with English keyboard) which confused the spellchecker somehow. Solved by removing duplicate languages from windows, only German with German keyboard and English with US-international keyboard were left, the same from Spellchecking languages in MS Office. No issues anymore.